# Customize the text "Total" in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, gettext

I would like to change the the "Total" text in my checkout page to "Total inkl. vat". I have tried different things without success…

Here is what I am targeting:

```
<?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
```

This is the code snippet. I've searched in all language files but i can't find anything. I've installed the **Q translate plugin** but I don't think it's the problem.

I could code it hard, but thats not a good solution because I've to do this edit in all my files.

How can I achieve this please?

Thanks

Comment: Is your entire site in a certain language and just that line isn't translating? Or you want to change the translation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**OPTION 1** *(best option)*

**[Overriding the woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) `checkout/review-order.php`** template.

> You need first *(if not done)* to **copy** the **`templates`** sub folder located in in **`woocommerce`** plugin folder to your active child theme (or theme) folde, and rename it **`woocommerce`**.

Once done in your active theme go to **`woocommerce > checkout`**, and open/edit
**`review-order.php`** template file.

At the end of this template you have this:

```
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

        <tr class="order-total">
            <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

So you will change:

```
<th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

To:

```
<th><?php _e( 'Total inkl. vat', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

Now you can save, you are done…

References:

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Woocommerce template checkout > review-order.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php)

---

**OPTION 2** *(Not ideal, see below)*

You could use wordpress [**`gettex()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) native function for that purpose, this way:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wc_renaming_checkout_total', 20, 3);
function wc_renaming_checkout_total( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {

    if( !is_admin() && is_checkout ) {
        if( $untranslated_text == 'Total' )
            $translated_text = __( 'Total inkl. vat','theme_slug_domain' );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

> **But** you will get **2 customized texts** in the prices table, because there is 2 **`"Total"`** texts (once in the first line after 'Products') and one time at the end…

**This code is tested and works.**

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479742/change-total-windows-on-thankyou-page) @LoicTheAztec

Comment: @loictheaztec - I used your solution for this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55309447/customize-cart-totals-and-checkout-totals-text-based-on-product-categories/55309532?noredirect=1#comment97360429_55309532), but noticed your code and comments were gone before I could upvote and comment on the adjustments I made to your suggestions. If you can put the responses back then I'll credit you and maybe link to this as a related question.

Comment: @Les Sorry, I have undeleted my answer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Any trick to target only one of the two stings in your option 2 ?