# WooCommerce - Customize "Total" text on Thankyou order received page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gettext, orders

In WooCommerce I have a problem on my thankyou page (once the customer has placed his order). I have tryed to change it manualy but the problem is that the code is generated in an unknown file which I can't find.

```
    <tfoot>
        <?php
                foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
    </tfoot>
```

This code give me all information in my order like a coupon the shipping etc.

[image]

On this picture I would like to replace the text in the black bordered rectangle (Here **`'Gesamt:'`** mean **`"Total"`** by **`"Total inkl. vat"`**

Also I want to remove the red bordered rectangle block: **`"Inkl. 19% MwSt."`**.

Is it possible?
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the extract of the end on **`woocommerce/order/order-details.php`** template that is loaded in thank you page.

> To override the **`'Total'`** text displayed by **`foreach`** loop with the method **`get_order_item_totals()`** applied to the **`$order`** object *(that generate an array of **`key/values`**)*, you have to add a condition for each language used by your web site. Here in my code you got english and german.

In your active theme go to **`woocommerce > order`**, and open/edit
**`order-details.php`** template file.

Replace the end of your template with this:

```
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            $order_item_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();
            $count_lines = count($order_item_totals) - 1;
            $count = 0;
            foreach ( $order_item_totals as $key => $total ) {
                $count++;
                // The condition to replace "Total:" text in english and german
                if( $total['label'] == 'Total:' || $total['label'] == 'Gesamt:')
                    $total_label = __( 'Total inkl. vat:', 'woocommerce' );
                else 
                    $total_label = $total['label'];
                // End of the condition
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo $total_label; // <== == Replaced $total['label'] by $total_label ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                // this should avoid displaying last line
                if( $count >= $count_lines ) break;
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', $order ); ?>

<?php if ( $show_customer_details ) : ?>
    <?php wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-customer.php', array( 'order' =>  $order ) ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now you can save, you are done…

**This code is tested and works.**

References:

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Woocommerce template checkout > review-order.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php)
- [Customize the text "Total" in WooCommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458027/customize-the-text-total-in-woocommerce-checkout-page/39460400#39460400)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a way to remove the extra described vat now from this site? Thanks

Comment: I can write you a email but i'll answer it here because if other people need this answer somethimes you know? I mean the red rectangled field from my picture. First I've added the incl. vat to the total label and now i want to remove the red field from this loop because i don't want to show the vat extra

Comment: @Johnny97 I have just really understand **completely** your question now. So I have updated your question to make it more clear and updated my answer (You have to test it as I haven't). Comment me here  if it works.

Comment: Omg I'm so happy :) thank you so much! It works fine for me.

Comment: I have a bad feeling to ask you again... but do you know a answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/39549281/6580560 I've tried to make a wordpress custom template for the account page and inserted <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_account_navigation' ); ?> this to it but my page got a error after that...

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think this would work for you

Just make sure that `inkl. 19%....` is correctly written.

```
foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo ($total['label']=='inkl. 19% Mwst.'?'Vat Only':$total['label']); ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help too!