# Customizing WooCommerce Shipping and Payment text labels on Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

While I am using the WooCommerce, I have got stuck in the `Checkout` page. I researched on these link and found many useful things help me to customize the page a lot:

[Customize the text “Total” in WooCommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458027/customize-the-text-total-in-woocommerce-checkout-page) 
[Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) 
[WooCommerce Customizer](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-customizer/)

However, I am still getting stuck in these fields.

[image: Fields cannot customize]

If someone know how to customize the text (free plugin, php code), please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Shipping methods labels** can be directly renamed for each Shipping zone just in WooCommerce settings > Shipping:
"Edit" the Shipping zone, then "Edit" each Shipping method renaming the Label as you like:

[image]

Samething For the **Payment methods**: Go to WooCommerce settings > Checkout:
Select the Payment method to edit in the available tabs.

[image]

So no need of coding or plugins… The only thing is that the shipping lables changes will be also in cart page if they are enabled for it.