# Woocommerce - Add to custom word in checkout and cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

i want to add custom text in checkout and cart page. 
what code do I need to write to the function.php file?
beside to the "total" word. Always static.
Thank you

https://i.hizliresim.com/nJ4dBR.jpg

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vACrV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the woocommerce checkout/review-order.php template.

You need first (if not done) to copy the templates sub folder located in in woocommerce plugin folder to your active child theme (or theme) folde, and rename it woocommerce.
Once done in your active theme go to woocommerce > checkout, and open/edit review-order.php template file.

At the end of this template you have this:

```
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total' ); ?>

    <tr class="order-total">
        <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total' ); ?>

</tfoot>
```

So you will change:

To:

Now you can save, you are done…

Hope this will helps you.
For more information,

- [Customize the text “Total” in WooCommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458027/customize-the-text-total-in-woocommerce-checkout-page)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy `cart/cart-totals.php` and `checkout/review-order.php` template files from `woocommerce/templates` to your theme's folder at `<your-theme's-folder>/woocommerce/`.

## Then modify following templates.

**Template Path: `<your-theme's-folder>/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php`**

```
    <tr class="order-total">
        <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**Template Path: `<your-theme's-folder>/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php`**

```
    <tr class="order-total">
        <th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

## Modification Example

Edit `<th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>` with, for example,

```
<th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span> <?php _e('some text here', 'mm-woocommerce'); ?> </span></th>
```

*We added  `<span> <?php _e('some text here', 'mm-woocommerce'); ?> </span>`*