# Customize Cart Totals and Checkout Totals Text based on product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to customize the text in Cart and Checkout order summary tables  based on the product category (or some other logic). For example, for the 'Total' text (see image) - if the cart contains products in a category called "Groceries", then I'd like for text in the order summary to be displayed as 'Totals Estimate' text (see image below). If the cart does not contain any grocery items, then I want the default text.

I found a solution that got me started, but need some more help.

Per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458027/customize-the-text-total-in-woocommerce-checkout-page), I copied over files from woocommerce/templates/ into my child theme and named it woocommerce/. From `review_order.php` file, I need to edit the section below for example.

```
<th><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

However, I can't just replace that with a hard-coded string as my text depends on logic. So, I need to replace the string with a function.

I want to instead do something like this below:

```
<th><?php _e( get_my_custom_text(), 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

, where `get_my_custom_text()` returns the appropriate text based on some logic e.g. categories of items in the cart.

1. Where would I need to place the file containing function `get_my_custom_text()` so that the `review_order.php` can see the function?
2. Is this the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

[image]

**Update:**
Following discussions below, I'm adding my `get_custom_text()` code. I've attempted to solve this two ways: first is the [woocommerce files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458027/customize-the-text-total-in-woocommerce-checkout-page) way  and second one is the suggestion below to use the `add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 )` hook. In both cases, `get_my_custom_text()` doesn't seem to work when inspecting the cart. See code below using the hook method. I've gotten an error on the get_cart_contents_count(), and also got the white screen of death

`[23-Mar-2019 11:14:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart_contents_count() on null in /opt/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php:446`

Also got:
`[23-Mar-2019 11:16:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /opt/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 279`

```
   add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
    function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

            switch ( $translated_text ) {
               case 'Total' :
                    $translated_text = __( get_my_custom_text(), 'woocommerce' );
                    break;
             }

                return $translated_text;
    }

        function get_my_custom_text()
        {
            $is_groceries = has_groceries();
            if($is_groceries){
                return 'Total Estimate';
            }else{
                return 'Total';
            }
        }

        //checks whether cart has any items in the "groceries" category
        function has_groceries()
        {

            if( !$cart = WC()->cart ){
                return false;
            }

          //not sure how error gets here if cart is null     
          write_log('cart contents: '. WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count());

            $categories = array(  
                '181' => 'groceries' 
              );

            foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
                foreach ($categories as $category => $value) {
                    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) ){
                        return true;
                     }
                  }
            }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: Actually, my initial question was to do with where I would place the get_my_custom_text() if I were to use the method for copying over woocommerce files. But as discussions continue, there is need to update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to get in the Log, the cart items count (in your function). This is not really useful.

I have simplified and revisited your code and I dont use `get_my_custom_text()` in the last function as using `has_groceries()` instead is simpler and effective:

```
// Custom function based on has_groceries() conditional function that returns a string
function get_my_custom_text() {
    return has_groceries() ? 'Total Estimate' : 'Total';
}

// Custom conditional function checking for a specific product category in cart items
function has_groceries() {
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ){
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            if( has_term( array('groceries'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) )
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Change 'Total' text conditionally
add_filter( 'gettext', 'changing_total_text_string', 10, 3 );
function changing_total_text_string( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    // Only in cart and checkout pages
    if ( ( ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) || is_cart() )
    && $text === 'Total' && $domain === 'woocommerce' && has_groceries() ) {
        $translated_text = __('Total Estimate');
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> This way it will avoid an endless loop on "Total" text replacement.

Comment: 1/ Question about log - this is just left over from a debug log

2/ I discovered the problem, but I cannot explain why. This line is the culprit and I don't know what the __(string, string) function does, and also the 'woocommerce' argument. This line is the reason I was running out of memory and getting into a seemingly endless loop.

Comment: Also, did you mean to have `&& $domain === 'woocommerce'` ?
What is the is_wc_endpoint_ur()?

Comment: To target only checkout page (and not "Order received" page which use checkout with a custom **endpoint** `order-received`), You have to use `is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url()`

Comment: Thanks - so if I want to target the 'Order received' page, then I will do the following `if (is_checkout() && is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ))` - is this correct?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm still having some minor issues, the code you provided doesn't work - so I'm trying to figure out and will get back, still seeing some endless loops even after I've taken out the get_my_custom_text().

Comment: @Les I have tested this answer code on a my test server with another product category and it works just perfectly… Now may be the problem can be that when using `has_term()`, the term need to be set for the product (so it not work for a parent term that is set on the product).

Comment: I still end up with endless loops. I stripped down the hook code even further, but no luck.
`add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_total_text_string', 10, 3 );
function change_total_text_string( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    if( $text === 'Total' && has_groceries() ){
            $translated_text = __('Total Estimate');
    }
    return $translated_text;
}`

Answer (score 1):

That method is fine, and you would add the function to your `functions.php` in your child theme.

However, the method below is likely better, as you don't need to modify woocommerce at all!  You'll still need your same function, but everything can reside in `functions.php` now.  This uses Wordpress's `gettext` [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext).

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'my_text_strings', 20, 3 );
function my_text_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Total' :
            $translated_text = __( get_my_custom_text(), 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a new issue now. In get_my_custom_text(), I determine whether the cart has items in groceries category by using global $woocommerce; $cart = $woocmmerce->cart; For some reason, it doesn't seem to work with this hook. I've successfully used the same logic to determine whether there are items that are in groceries category. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Les, this filter is likely being called before the Woocommerce cart totals are determined.  Did you have the same issue when you tried your method that you posted above? What doesn't work when you try `$woocommerce->cart`?

Comment: Having the same issue all around. When I try `$woocommerce->cart`, I start to get memory exhaustion errors on the WC logs `CRITICAL Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /opt/wordpress/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 4157`. The webpage becomes unresponsive and goes blank.  How do I tell whether the filter is called before WC cart totals? Are there other alternatives for me to achieve what I want?

Comment: @Les I'm not sure.  Can you try using this? `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count()`

Comment: I got the following error:Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_cart_contents_count() on null. The cart has 1 items.

Comment: I've updated question with the code (using your hook method and  `get_my_custom_text()` function.

Comment: after some debugging, this line is caused the memory exhaustion errors as is was getting into a seemingly endless loop. `$translated_text = __( get_my_custom_text(), 'woocommerce' );`. I don't know what that __(string, string) function does, nor the 'woocommerce' argument. What does that function do?

Comment: It globalizes the string, making it available for translations.  You don't technically need it.  If you duplicate the template file into your child theme, you can completely omit the method posted above, delete the `_e` function in the woocommerce theme, and simply put your custom function.  Try that!  If need be we can go to chat on stackexchange to figure it out

Comment: This was helpful. I combined input from comments and solved it. Question - what's the difference between $translated and $test in the arguments, and when do you decide to evaluate one vs the other?

Comment: @Les - `$translated` is the translated text and `$text` is the untranslated text.  I suppose you'd use the one you needed to use case by case